# Excel: Dependent Dropdown Lists on Dynamic Content

Tags: excel

I've imported a list of clients and their websites from the Google Analytics (GA) API in the following format:

```
Account     Profile
Client 1    www.client1.com
Client 1    sub.client1.com
Client 1    tst.client1.com
Client 2    www.client2.com
Client 3    www.client3.com
Client 3    sub.client3.com
```

What I need is a dropdown list with the unique accounts names and then a second dropdown list with the dependent profiles of the chosen account. Something that looks like this:

```
Account     Profile
Client 1    www.client1.com
            sub.client1.com
            tst.client1.com
```

We add accounts and profiles to GA all the time, so the list will need to be refreshed every time we run the report.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: See this post [Excel dependent dropdown lists (With/without VBA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151165/excel-dependent-dropdown-lists-with-without-vba)

Comment: Thank you. I've read that post and the link offered by the chosen answer within it and the solutions offered all require the lists to be pre-determined. As I'm using an API call, with differing dynamic data, this isn't practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As long as you have this list **sorted by Account***, you can use a mixture of `Offset` `CountA` to give you all the ranges you need.

### Steps would be:

a. Get unique values from Account column (i'm using VBA for this step but you could use Frequency formula to mash this too -- I'd avoid it if you can use VBA for this). Something along the lines:

```
    Sub FindUniqueValues(SourceRange As Range, TargetCell As Range)
        SourceRange.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , TargetCell, True
    End Sub
```

(I've called this from my worksheet_change event for ease but if you are using vba to pull G.A. data, just integrate into that)

b. Feed this to Named Range (Say `AccountsRange`) that has the forumla `=$D$2:INDEX($D$2:$D$5000,COUNTA($D$2:$D$5000))` -- This assumes you specified `D1` as `TargetCell` for previous step and unique values won't be more than 4999 (1st value is row title in my case -- Hence starting from `D2`)

c. Add this Named Range `AccountsRange` as source for Data Validation List -- Your account combo box is done at this point. I'm going to assume you put this combo box in `E2` and I'll build on this to derive the second ComboBox

d. Create a new Named Range say `ProfilesRange` with formula `=INDEX($B$1:$B$5000,MATCH($E$2,$A$1:$A$5000,0),1):INDEX($B$1:$B$5000,COUNTIF($A‌​$1:$A$5000,$E$2)+MATCH($E$2,$A$1:$A$5000,0)-1,1)`
*Note: if you copy paste from here the above formula will contain a line-break invisible character after `COUNTIF($A` and excel will complain about invalid formula, just retype `$A$1` part of `COUNTIF` and it should be fine*

`A2` is the start of Account column of G.A. imported data (`A1` being the title and assuming maximum of 4999 data rows here) `E2` is the Comboboxed cell from previous AccountsRange dropdown step. -1 in `Match` step is needed as the offset needs to be 0 for first value row and not 1 which will be returned from `Match`. Second 1 is column offset (it can be more if you need to hop several columns to get secondary data). `CountIf` is pretty self explanatory :) This basically gets us the number of cells we need in final range from the starting point.

e. Create your new Data Validation List that uses ProfilesRange as its source and your secondary combo box is done.

### Issues that may arise:

1. When you change Accounts Combobox, Profiles combobox will probably error out as the values in profiles are unlikely to be present in new client. You could either ignore the error (it will fix itself once you select correct value from newly refreshed dropdown or throw a bit more of VBA fairy dust in there to clear the drop down cell when the value changes in `E2`.
2. Data Validation List compalains about evaluating to an error when you try to setup ProfilesRange. It is safe to ignore this error and continue. It basically means nothing computable was returned by ProfilesRange (most probably because you haven't selected anything in AccountsRange that actually computes to a ProfilesRange -- of course assuming your actual cell ranges for formulae used here are actually correct for your sheet)

Thanks to [osknows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/688334/osknows) for his tip and improvement on forumlae (in comments below): *Avoid use of OFFSET its very slow over large ranges and is volatile. =OFFSET($D$2,0,0,COUNTA($D$2:$D$5000) can be replaced with =$D$2:INDEX($D$2:$D$5000,COUNTA($D$2:$D$5000)) for the named range.* (this tip has been incorporated into this solution now, so you won't see the original Offset forumlae unless you check version history)

Comment: Thanks Maverik. I'll code it up and post my vote in the next 15 minutes.

Comment: Tried it and the drop-down errors immediately - "The Source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?" - meaning it doesn't work at all, at the minute. I've checked all the references twice to make sure they're correct, so not sure what's up. Any ideas?

Comment: Will it be possible to see your draft sheet? I could probably figure it out a lot quicker if i could see the actual thing in action. I'm around for another hour roughly and hopefully this won't take long to correct. I did this entire code in my own worksheet before posting and it was working fine with your data.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. I'll make a copy and ss it - the original has commercially sensitive data.

Comment: No problem. I'll recreate my sheet and post a link to it and you can plugin your values and hopefully the comparison will let you see where the problem is.

Comment: NVM!! I figured it out! Ignore the error and continue. The problem is you don't have anything in AccountsRange Dropdown cell that actually computes to a list that ProfilesRange can use. Put something valid in there and profiles will automatically get you fresh data

Comment: My Sheet - Edit enabled if you wish to convey something back via that sheet : https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0Bz3sD8TuouyANTcxOTJjNmItYTgzMS00OTNhLTkwOGYtNzNlYjk5MjY0NmRj&hl=en_US&authkey=CIiVw5kK

Comment: heh just noticed :) it was a pleasure!

Comment: @Maverik a small tip... Avoid use of `OFFSET` its very slow over large ranges and is volatile. `=OFFSET($D$2,0,0,COUNTA($D$2:$D$5000)` can be replaced with `=$D$2:INDEX($D$2:$D$5000,COUNTA($D$2:$D$5000))` for the named range.

Comment: Cool, thank you for the tip! Never knew I could combine Index like that. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Maverik np. For completeness you could also change the named range `ProfilesRange` with formula `=OFFSET($A$2,MATCH($E$2,$A$2:$A$5000,0)-1,1,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$5000,$E$2)` to `=INDEX($B$1:$B$5000,MATCH($E$2,$A$1:$A$5000,0),1):INDEX($B$1:$B$5000,COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5000,$E$2)+MATCH($E$2,$A$1:$A$5000,0)-1,1)`. It's longer but is safer than `OFFSET`. Of course everything falls over if the data is not sorted :)

Comment: I had tried for an hour before editing my answer but got lost in index address string (I entered one too many index in without realising -- noticed now after looking at your formula). Thank you again for teaching me something new.