# Excel VBA - How can I make sure that the dropdown list contains no duplicates?

Tags: vba, excel

With the following code, one could set dropdown list for the cell D7 via VBA (for the detailed context, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151165/excel-dependent-dropdown-lists-with-without-vba/6151484?noredirect=1#comment78689542_6151484) (the answer which was not approved)):

```
   With Range("D7").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=$" & Chr(68 + col) _
             & "$2:$" & Chr(68 + col) & "$10" 'Range("E2:E4").Offset(0, col - 1)
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

However, every value in the cells from Chr(68 + col)2 to Chr(68 + col)10 is included in the dropdown list, including the duplicates.

Is there any way to only include the unique values in the dropdown list?

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: not in the code you have provided.  You will need to create the list separately, using vba or formulas,  and refer to that location.

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/05/25/create-a-drop-down-list-containing-only-unique-distinct-alphabetically-sorted-text-values-using-excel-array-formula/)