# How to call a named list?

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for some help on calling a named list in a VBA code. Here is more details : I created some named list using the Name Manager (in the formula tab). What I would like to do is to display the items contained in the named list in a Combobox depending on the value of an other combobox.

To give a simple example : if I select "New York" in the other combobox, the first one only displays elements available in New York instead of the elements available in all cities.
My problem is that whenever I use the Range("Name").Select, I only get the name of the named list and not the following items.

[image: Here is the tool I used to create the named list]

Moreover, some of the named list gives me an error when calling them such as :
Range("Site_Mourenx").Select
Select Method of Range class has failed.

Thanks for your help.
After Gary's student message, I tried to just change the code to send the value of each cell in my combobox :

```
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("Site_Mourenx")
        Me.ComboBox_emplacement.List = cell.Value
    Next cell
```

However, I get an error message telling me :
Impossible to define the property List. Property table index not valid.
Is the fact that my combobox is placed in an userform a problem ?
It's weird because I already used the .List on other combobox content and it worked totally fine.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `Range("Name")` allows you to refer to the named list, which you seem to know already. How does that not answer the question you posed in the title? What is the difference between "calling" a list and merely referring to it?

Comment: `Range("Name")` is the answer here. You are asking the wrong question

Comment: Well, whenever I use it, I just get the name of the named list and not the following items. Does each item needs to be in a single cell ?

Comment: So ask about that instead! Which means, you will need to show examples of how you are using (code, sample data, expected output, etc.)

Comment: A name is a string. `Range("Name")` is a range, not a string. I don't know what you mean when you say that this just gives you the name of the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel dependent dropdown lists (With/without VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6151165/11683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worksheet, I assign the Name `New_York` to cells **D1** through **D4**:

[image]

This allows me, in VBA, to process the components like:

```
Sub WhatsInAName()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("New_York")
        MsgBox cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

You would use the components to fill your combobox.

**EDIT#1:**

Perhaps something like:

```
Sub UNTESTED()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("New_York")
        somecombobox.AddItem cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: It's really close from what I want, I will try to add it to my code and will return the results soon. Thanks and excuse me for my small knowledge about objects.

Comment: @Jorondah See my **EDIT#1**  I put thing in a combobox with `.AddItem` ...............If this is of no value to you, I will delete the Answer...............

Comment: It works perfectly fine, I thought I could get the entire list using the .List. I will try to edit my code to add condition and see i'f I get an other problem. I'll answer tomorrow. Thanks for your help anyway, I keep you tuned.

Comment: I addded some conditions to it and didn't encounter any problem. Thank you for your help, you solved the problem !