# How to populate values in a drop-down list dynamically

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, dropdown

I have the below source data(the original data has thousands of rows)

```
Form  field 
Form1 field11
Form1 field12
Form2 field21
Form2 field22
```

In a separate sheet, I want to have 2 dropdown lists in field A1 and B1.

The drop-down list in A1 should populate the list of forms eg `Form1, Form2` ,etc.

The drop-down list on B1 should populate the field based on selection from A1.

For ex if `Form 1` is selected in A1 ,B1 should populate field 11 and field 12 in drop-down list.

Comment: Please fix typos and provide input, output, expectation,

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @wils I could not  find any solution hence seeking solutions here

Comment: [Excel dependent dropdown lists (With/without VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151165/excel-dependent-dropdown-lists-with-without-vba)

Comment: @wils thanks for sharing the link. However this solution wouldn't work for my data as i would need to create individual columns for each form.

Comment: Please show the initial code that you have done so far to be fair with others who were required the same condition.

Comment: Also share your version of Excel

Answer (score 0):

screenshots (in reverse order) and function (1st step, bottom)/[sheet here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98Ce6cD8tytai89ut?e=OkzGsX) refer:

**4] Result**

[image: Desired outcome: Dependent 2nd field]

**3] Validation list 'selected cells' relies upon named range:**

[image: Named range 'field_selected']

[image: Named range (Main Ribbon: Formulas, Name Manager....]

*(make sure to include # at end to extend to bottom of spill range - assumes you have Excel as part of Office 365 package)*

**2] Additional spill range specified in cell F4 as follows:**

[image: Filter function, dependent upon first validation cell (selection: H2)]

**1] Filter function:**

```
=FILTER(E4:E7,D4:D7=H3)
```